# how to discard duplicate zero crossing values in solve_ivp

Tags: python, scipy, ode, differential-equations

I'm solving the ode `phi_ddot = const1 - const2 * (phi_dot)^2` using `scipy.solve_ivp` and trying to track an event of `phi_dot = 0` (used a basic event function that returns `y[1]`, where `y` is a vector that represents `[phi,phi_dot]`).

I printed the solution before the zero crossing and after it, and I noticed that the zero crossing itself (in the example below, it is the value `1.905e-13`) is present in both vectors:

```
phi_dot before = [5.082e+01, 3.622e+00, 1.905e-13]
phi_dot after  = [1.905e-13, -9.991e-04, -1.099e-02, ...])
```

For my purposes, it is crucial that all values in the vector will have the same sign, but as you can see, in `phi_dot after`, all values are negative except the value of the zero crossing.

Is there a way to change this output such that the sign of the zero crossing will correspond to the sign of the values in the vector in which it is contained?

Comment: This is a bug in solve_ivp or a missing interface of brentq. The root finder just returns the first root approximation that is good enough, without providing the enclosing or bracketing interval. And the integrator loop does not care to move the node to after the root. So you have the move it manually. You know the point and its derivative, so you can compute the Newton update. Move the point twice that distance

Comment: what exactly is the newton update?

Comment: You have a value `y` close to zero of the component of interest and the derivative `Dy`, either from another component or by evaluating the derivatives function. You want to advance to the root and a bit over. In first approximation `0=y+s*Dy` gives `s=-y/Dy` and `y+2*s*Dy` should have the opposite sign of `y`. Of course you only need to apply this if `s > 0`.